# Oracle 11g Menu XML to MMB Error and Compile Errors

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Using Oracle 11g Forms, I'm having issues compiling a Menu MMB.

I am converting the MMB to XML, making a mass set of changes.
Then I convert the XML back to MMB.
But when I go to compile strange things occur.

I use the following to compile

```
for %%f IN (*.xml) do C:\oracle\MidHome\asinst_1\bin\frmxml2f OVERWRITE=YES USERID=<userid>/<pwd>@<db> %%f
```

it compiles but does not product an MMX it produces an ERR file which says:

No PL/SQL source code in menu item "my menu item"

But if i open the MMB, there IS PLSQL code in that menu item.

===============================

NOW If i open the form connect to my database and compile, the compilation error window open and it also states "No PL/SQL source code in menu...."
But it's there!

IF on the other hand.  I open the MMB and make all my changes BY HAND ( a tedious and lengthy process)  No compilation errors are generated.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a simular problem with the forms api.

If you got a menu like:

```
Menu1
  Action 1
  Action 2
Menu2
  Action 3
  Action 4
```

Then it is possible with the API to put an empty pl/sql code behind Menu1 and Menu2.

Probably converting your MMB in XML makes empty tags or uses the wrong command-type. Or the other way around if you change the XML to MMB again this happens.

If it is the first case you can adjust it.
If it is the second case you can test this by just opening the properties panel and checking all command-types and switching between them.